# Memory leaks from closures other than circular references

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Modern day browsers don't leak from circular references, they can handle them. Are there other ways in which closures leak memory then? Something the current chrome (v43) garbage collector wouldn't catch?

Answer (score 0):

A classic are event handlers that aren't detached properly. jQuery automatically detaches event handlers from elements when they are removed from the DOM.

Timer handlers are in the same league. Other than that, if a closure's context is hanging around there's probably an unexpected reference somewhere keeping it alive.

To spot it, simplify your code to the minimum and by doing so test it. Once you've removed the leak you'll know what it was. That's a long way, I know, but that's that.

For the specifics of your browser I wouldn't know.